# Tensorflow: How can I find out the BIG tensors?

Tags: tensorflow

I encountered the OOM problem on tensorflow, warning that it OOM when allocating XXX tensor. But I believe that it's because some other big tensors occupied too much memory instead of THAT error tensor, since I've ever used that structure with the same shape with lower total memory usage and no OOM occurred.

And another hard thing is that the BIG tensor is RUNTIME TENSOR, not the so-called trainable parameters, so I cannot observe the params size before session runs, what I can do is to just wait the OOM to occur after it begins to run.